# Extraer todos los textos entre dos delimitadores dentro de un código html

Tags: php

Tal como dice el texto, tengo un código html largo, de unas 1000 lineas aproximadamente, donde hay montones de  y , aquí un ejemplo

```
<td class="textleft"><a href="/DIRECCION-URL.html">TEXTO DE LA URL</a></td><td>DESCRIPCION</td><td class="mobile-hidden">POBLACION</td></tr>
```

Ese patrón se repite cerca de 100 veces en todo el código html, y de ese código yo necesitaría poder extraer literalmente esto --> /DIRECCION-URL.html por un lado, y TEXTO DE LA URL por otro lado, en un array asociativo por supuesto.

He hecho varias pruebas con preg_match_all en php pero la única que me ha resultado me retorna valores con http que son justo los que quiero omitir.

Debo reconocer que este código que pongo es copiado y que simplemente lo he trasteado un poco para intentar adaptarlo a lo que necesito, pero no logro sacarlo adelante

**preg_match_all('#/[^,\s()<>]+(?:([\w\d]+)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $contenidohtml, $resultados);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con xpath puedes lograrlo

con `//td[@class='textleft']/a/@href` obtienes todos los valores del atributo  href (`@href`), dentro de todos los links (`a`), dentro de de todas la celdas [`td`] que si attributo class sea 'textleft' `[@class='textleft']`

con `//td[@class='textleft']/a/text()` obtienes el texto `(/text())` dentro de todos los links (`/a`), dentro de de todas la celdas (`td`) que su attributo class sea 'textleft' `[@class='textleft']`

```
<?php
$string = '<tr><td class="textleft"><a href="/DIRECCION-URL.html">TEXTO DE LA URL</a></td><td>DESCRIPCION</td><td class="mobile-hidden">POBLACION</td></tr>
<tr><td class="textleft"><a href="/DIRECCION-URL.html">TEXTO DE LA URL</a></td><td>DESCRIPCION</td><td class="mobile-hidden">POBLACION</td></tr>
<tr><td class="textleft"><a href="/DIRECCION-URL.html">TEXTO DE LA URL</a></td><td>DESCRIPCION</td><td class="mobile-hidden">POBLACION</td></tr>';

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$urls = $xpath->query("//td[@class='textleft']/a/@href");
$textos=$xpath->query("//td[@class='textleft']/a/text()");
foreach ($urls as $i => $node) {
    echo "url: ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
foreach ($textos as $i => $node) {
    echo "texto: ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: He tardado, pero sí, lo solucioné usando tu código y re-adaptándolo para otras cosas que también necesitaba jeje.